# How to upsert nested array object mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a document which looks like this

```
{
 _id:'asasasasa23sdsdsd',
 source:'page',
 url:[]
}
```

I need to upsert some values/objects to the `url` array. the objects that need to be upserted looks like this.

```
{
"type" : "blog",
"value" : "hello blog",
"id" : "1815f620-b45c-4230-85bb-7ba90ac330ed",
"datetime" : "2019-12-26 15:58:33"
}
```

Then it would look like this

```
{
 _id:'asasasasa23sdsdsd',
 source:'page',
 url:[{
    "type" : "admin",
    "value" : "hello admin",
    "id" : "1815f620-b45c-4230-85bb-7ba90ac330ed",
    "datetime" : "2019-12-26 15:58:33"
     },
   {
    "type" : "blog",
    "value" : "hello blog",
    "id" : "1815f620-b45c-4230-85bb-7ba90ac330ed",
    "datetime" : "2019-12-26 15:58:33"
   }
  ]
}
```

Here the id and the type fields are unique. I need to insert them if they do not exist or update them if they do.
This is the code that I have tried

```
db.collection(TABLE_NAME).update(
      { source: data.source },
      {
        source: data.source,
        url: [data.urls]
      },
      { upsert: true }
    );
```

With this, it just replaces the array object with a new object. How to upsert instead of replacing the object?

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will help.

```
    let arr = [
   {
    "type" : "admin",
    "value" : "hello admin",
    "id" : "1815f620-b45c-4230-85bb-7ba90ac330ed",
    "datetime" : "2019-12-26 15:58:33"
     },
   {
    "type" : "blog",
    "value" : "hello blog",
    "id" : "1815f620-b45c-4230-85bb-7ba90ac330ed",
    "datetime" : "2019-12-26 15:58:33"
   }
    ];

    db.users.update(
      { _id: doc._id },
      {
        $set: {
          "url": arr
        }
      }
    );
```